# Amadeus test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers and other api V2 hotel api return a 401 invalid access token

Tags: amadeus

I'm working on a hotel booking application, and trying to integrate amadeus api. I'm using the test api base url https://test.api.amadeus.com
when sending a request for flight-offers i get the response and the token is valid.
But when i'm trying to use the hotel-offers end point with the same token(before it expires in 30 mins) it returns a 401 message.
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=LON&destinationLocationCode=NYC&departureDate=2022-01-16&adults=1&travelClass=ECONOMY works

[flight offers endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOKu7.png)

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=LON&checkInDate=2022-01-05&checkOutDate=2022-01-07 does not work

[hotel offers endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYqBA.png)

i know that a token expires after 30 min and took that into consideration.
Is there a problem with this endpoint:
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers

Comment: Hello @grace, please we suggest you to send an email at developers@amadeus.com for the question.

Comment: okay, i will try to contact them

Comment: @grace Hi Grace did you manage to find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem... The v3 version of the API doesn't have the same option...

Comment: I sent an email to the developer team, they told me the issue was with the V2 api endpoint, they were working on it ...  Now its working